# Caps Lock is bugged

Tags: keyboard

I have HyperX Alloy Core RGB keyboard (HX-KB5ME2-US). Sometimes when I turn off caps lock, LED on keyboard is still on. After another press, LED is on, and caps lock is on.
Why is this happening? Is that bug in keyboards firmware or in windows driver? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an existing problem on this keyboard that exists in its firmware. Users [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/HyperX/comments/assus8/alloy_fps_pro_keys_randomly_stop_working_and_caps/) complain about the same thing, but HyperX support has said they will replace the board if you send it in and they can replicate the problem. [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/HyperX/comments/assus8/alloy_fps_pro_keys_randomly_stop_working_and_caps/esto1dt?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) comment offers some solutions if you don't want to send it back and are willing to get a bit technical.